# How to install an older version of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

If I'm having a problem with Android Studio, and want to see if it exists in a previous version, where do I go to find the older (obsolete) version of Android Studio?  There's no link to previous versions on the download page, only other download options, does not give older versions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A good way to try something in another version of Android Studio is to make a second installation.

You can download previous versions through a third-party site from the following links (thanks [Nikhil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43391981/3549440)):

- [For Windows](https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/old)
- [For Mac](https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/mac/old)

Unfortunately, I couldn't find archives for linux.

The official archive download site is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html), but most if not all of the older version links are dead.

You may also want to download the IDE only and set it up to point to your existing SDK.  To do this, in your new installation of Android Studio, go to

***Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager***

and under

***Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK***,

enter the android SDK location path of the other install.

---

**Note on downloads:**

If you know the version you want, a link like http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-1-3 will get you to a download page for 2.1.3 via the tools.android.com site, if you prefer.

**EDIT** :

Above site doesn't have older versions after V2.3. You can now download previous version from the following link :

[Windows & Mac](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Comment: Sadly the link above no longer has old builds - in fact it doesn't have *any* builds, and the pages it links to only has "current build" and "preview build" - no previous versions :-(

Comment: These links are no longer working, at least for studio version 2.3.0.

Comment: @adeady Did you find any other place where we could download an older version?

Comment: @droidster One this page http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-3-0 the only link that actually downloads something is the 2nd windows link.  Linux and mac do not work, nor do the other 3 windows.  So its really *not* a true solution at this point.  About to log a bug with AS as the current versions new emulators do not work right

Comment: @adeady Thanks for the reply. Found it in my time machine backup. :) Luckily!

Comment: @Nate The link you provided is inactive.

Comment: It looks like previous versions are now hosted here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html.  Unfortunately, all links are dead except a few of the latest versions.  If you want to go through a third party site, this one seems to work: https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/old.  It was on the linked question.

Comment: Looks like all the .dmg files at uptodown.com are corrupted.

Comment: Most of them have errors when trying to install. "Installer Integrity check failed!"

Comment: I wouldn't recommend downloading from a 3rd party. You can find all versions on the Android Studio Download Archives page: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: The links have been 404ed.