# android studio download windows XP

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-xp

I have been trying to download `Android Studio` for the past week or so and haven't been able to. I'm still running `windows XP` on a `Dell d430` (If it helps). The error happened when it was extracting a file. If you could provide a link which can download android studio for `Windows XP` on a `Dell d430`, please do. Thank you for your time (by the way I know that this question doesn't have much to do with programming).

Comment: Ifit helps the errror occurred when the computer was extracting a file named:  sa-jdi.jar

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Android Studio which version?

Comment: IMHO, a Dell D430 is unlikely to be able to run Android Studio effectively. But the download link is the one that you are already using, most likely: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the error was that it could not extract the file called: sa-jdi.jar

Comment: @Hareesh I tried to install the newest version of android studio (probably not the best idea).

Comment: @CommonsWare I will try to download the win 32 one that was in your link. I will tell you how it works.

Comment: The answers are correct: the current Android Studio does not support XP. You should check the system requirements listed on [the Android Studio page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to see if your machine comes anywhere close to the specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Check this page
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio)

Version 1.X only supported for Windows XP

Comment: thanks for the info, I'll try the 1.X and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

The self-extraction that the installation binary performs has definitely nothing to do with what version of Studio you try to install or whether it supports XP or not, the installation shall start and tell you if there's a problem.

Actually, you can run Android Studio fine on Windows XP, I do it on a Dell Inspiron 9200 (Intel Pentium 1.7GHz 2GB RAM). I even installed the latest version 2.3.2 and Java SDK 8(which is required: make sure it's not just JRE 8 but both). Java SDK 8 complains about XP being old but installs fine. There's a snag in Studio tools with an XP dll but that can be fixed, read on.

The downloading doesn't involve extracting as your question implies, if it does you haven't got the right download. When downloading is done and the installation is started, that's when the extraction begins.

- If you didn't download from **developer.android.com/studio/** it might contain malware. You could scan it but being a huge file(approx. 2GB) you have to download a scanner, e.g **https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-install-bitdefender-on-windows-xp-and-windows-vista-1453.html**
- For Windows versions newer than XP / Vista refer to **www.bitdefender.com/toolbox/freeapps/desktop/**

After the download is done (and verified if needed), your problem with the installation program might be one or more of, but not limited to:

- The file you downloaded is corrupt. Try downloading another copy.
- Corruption on your hard drive, however less likely if the same file fails to extract again and again.
- Your Memory or CPU is failing. Very unlikely if the same file fails even twice.
- Corruption in the current directory data block or a  problem with the directory path. Try creating a folder at the root with no spaces in its name ( e.g. C:\Download ), move the installation file to it and run it from there.

About support/compatibility: it's not unpermitted trying to install and run, and I for one am all for it. But if it's not supported and you run into problems, another way to go rather then upgrading your system is to downgrade your software. Here you have suggestions, but take care scanning them for malware. For smaller files(current max 128MB) you can upload to Google owned **www.virustotal.com/**

- **[How to install an older version of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258183/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-android-studio)**

Finally, the dll problem in Android Studio 2.3.2 is with the adb program requiring a newer version of WS2_32.dll (it's technical: never mind). A work around is to download an older version of adb:

- **forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/general/psa-fix-adb-doesnt-winxp-t3403955**

Or, as the suggestion here says: if you're feeling adventurous, you can always grab the new WS2_32.dll, then scan it by uploading to **www.virustotal.com/**, and register it with the command **regsvr32  WS2_32.dll** (google regsvr32 for more info on that).

- **coderanch.com/t/667002/Android-ADB-find-entry-point**

/z

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, Windows XP is not supported. You should find a way to update your operating system. Consider installing Linux on your old machine. Recent distributions will work albeit very slowly.