# Where did i get list of all versions of Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am stuck in my Android Studio and not able to open it. So i want to install new Android Studio with a lower version than previous. So, where did i get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install an older version of Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258183/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, on the below link you are able to get all the versions of Android Studio.

https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/old

Go and get your suitable version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have old versions:

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Not all versions are available.