# Updated my android studio How to get previous versions?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

[This is the older version which I want to have?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAu33.png)

[This is one to which I accidentally updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz3RA.png)

after updation the properties and layout tabs changed drastically ,taking much time.
plz tell me Is there any setting option which I can change and I have tried reinstalling older version but this overview remains same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install an older version of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258183/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it and then simply re-install the older version.

You can download it from here:

https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/old

Comment: Exit the program then delete the settings folder in "C:\Users\[Your user name]\.AndroidStudiox.x", after that restart android studio

Comment: Notice that the folder is hidden so you need to enable showing hidden files

Comment: .gradle folder also must be deleted?

Comment: Yes delete it no problem in that.