# Deployment Target Options is not visible and Getting "No Device Found" Error in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools, android-studio-3.5

I had just installed Android Studio 3.5 and in that I can not run app on my phone via ADB.
What could be the reason.? Getting below error and I don't see option to select "Deployment Target" in Run > Edit Configurations > app > Deployment Target Options.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to run in console: `adb devices` and tell, what's the result

Comment: I tried that, but is not showing any devices as connected.

Comment: Is your smartphone unlocked when you connect it to computer? Some models are invisible for computer when they are not unlocked

Comment: Yes it was unlocked. I had checked all the things required to connect phone, like developer options, USB debugging option etc.
I had installed few ADB softwares as well..

Comment: Does your computer see a smartphone, can you get access to smartphone's storage on computer?

Comment: Yes, i can access phones storage..

Comment: just install AndroidStudio 3.4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258183/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-android-studio Work For Me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got solution  to this problem.
I installed ADB interface driver from http://adbdriver.com/

Thanks for your time friends.

Comment: But in your comment, about 2 hours ago, you said you already have the `adb` :)

Comment: Yes, I had installed ADB interface driver but still it was not working for me.
may be I installed wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you have disabled the Firebase Testing plugin in Android Studio.

To make Deployment Target Options reappear, go to Preferences > Plugins > Firebase Testing > check.